# How can I check wrong username and password in C# from SQL?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I just try to check wrong username, password and I want message box says " wrong username, password".

When I enter correct username and password, it's okay, I can login.
When I enter wrong username and password the first time, I get a message box but even if I enter the correct username and password the 2nd time, I get the error again.

I think return is not working.

baglanti means connection

My code is here:

```
private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtboxID.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your username..", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        if (txtboxPW.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your password..", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        string getid = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username='" + txtboxID.Text + "'";
        string getpw = "SELECT password FROM user WHERE password='" + txtboxPW.Text + "'";
        SQLiteCommand gettingid = new SQLiteCommand(getid, baglanti);
        SQLiteCommand gettingpw = new SQLiteCommand(getpw, baglanti);
        baglanti.Open();
        
        object idfind = gettingid.ExecuteScalar();
        if (idfind == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("wrong username", "Error");
            return;
        }

        object pwfind = gettingpw.ExecuteScalar();
        if (pwfind == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("wrong password", "Error");
            return;
        }
        baglanti.Close();
        string id = idfind.ToString();
        string pass = pwfind.ToString();

        if (txtboxID.Text == id || txtboxPW.Text == pass)
        {
            guverteBtn.Visible = true;
            makineBtn.Visible = true;
            loginBtn.Visible = false;
            logincontrolTxt.Text = "Login Succesfully !";
            logincontrolTxt.ForeColor = Color.White;
            logincontrolTxt.Location = new Point(200, 393);
            regBTN.Visible = false;
            resetBTN.Visible = false;
            txtboxID.Text = "";
            txtboxPW.Text = "";
        }
        
        else
        {
            logincontrolTxt.Text = "Invalid ID or Password !";
            logincontrolTxt.Location = new Point(180, 393);
            logincontrolTxt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            txtboxID.Text = "";
            txtboxPW.Text = "";
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***. also: ***never*** store passwords in plain text.

Comment: There are many, many hundreds of posts here showing how to properly store and retrieve user credentials **and** properly manage your DB provider objects (for instance do not use a single global connection object over and over).  They are easy to find, so feel free to help yourself at your leisure.

Comment: i am just new coding guys can you show edit my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made some minor modifications to your code, but as others mentioned, you need to change your SQL query to a parameterized one to prevent SQL injection.

Also always try to connect/query the database less as possible, if you can get your data at once, to improve your application performance.

I did not test the code below, but it should resolve your problem.

```
private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtboxID.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your username..", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    if (txtboxPW.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your password..", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    string getid = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username='" + txtboxID.Text + "' AND password='" + txtboxPW.Text + "'"; //Security Issue: SQL Injection 

    SQLiteCommand gettingid = new SQLiteCommand(getid, baglanti);
    try {
        baglanti.Open();
    
        object idfind = gettingid.ExecuteScalar();
        if (idfind == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid user credentials!", "Error");
        }
        else 
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(idfind)))
            {
                guverteBtn.Visible = true;
                makineBtn.Visible = true;
                loginBtn.Visible = false;
                logincontrolTxt.Text = "Login Succesful!";
                logincontrolTxt.ForeColor = Color.White;
                logincontrolTxt.Location = new Point(200, 393);
                regBTN.Visible = false;
                resetBTN.Visible = false;
                txtboxID.Text = "";
                txtboxPW.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                logincontrolTxt.Text = "Invalid ID or Password !";
                logincontrolTxt.Location = new Point(180, 393);
                logincontrolTxt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                txtboxID.Text = "";
                txtboxPW.Text = "";
            }
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unhandled exception!", "Error");
    }
    finally {
        baglanti.Close();
    }      
    
}
```